# What should my LESS @import path be?

Tags: django, less, django-compressor

Here's the scenario:

I'm running Django 1.3.1, utilizing staticfiles, and django-compressor (latest stable) to, among other things, compile LESS files.

I have an "assets" directory that's hooked into staticfiles with `STATICFILES_DIRS` (for project-wide static resources). In that directory I have a "css" directory and in that a "lib.less" file that contains LESS variables and mixins.

So the physical path is `<project_root>/assets/css/lib.less` and it's served at `/static/css/lib.less`.

In one of my apps' static directory, I have another LESS file that needs to import the one above. The physical path for that is `<project_root>/myapp/static/myapp/css/file.less` and it would be served at `/static/myapp/css/file.less`.

My first thought was:

```
@import "../../css/lib.less"
```

(i.e. based on the URL, go up to levels from `/static/myapp/css` to `/static/`, then traverse down into `/static/css/lib.less`).

However, that doesn't work, and I've tried just about every combination of URLs and physical paths I can think of and all of them give me `FilterError`s in the template, resulting from not being able to find the file to import.

Anyone have any ideas what the actual import path should be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After tracking down exactly where the error was coming from in the django-compressor source. It turns out to be directly passed from the shell. Which clued me into removing all the variables and literally just trying to get the `lessc` compiler to parse the file.

Turns out it wants a relative path from the source file to the file to be imported in terms of the physical filesystem path. So I had to back all the way out to my `<project_root>` and then reference `assets/css/lib.less` from there. The actual import that finally worked was:

```
@import "../../../../assets/css/lib.less"
```

What's very odd though is that lessc would *not* accept an absolute filesystem path (i.e. `/path/to/project/assets/css/lib.less`). I'm not sure why.

**UPDATE (02/08/2012)**

Had a complete "DUH" moment when I finally pushed my code to my staging environment and ran `collectstatic`. The @import path I was using worked fine in development because that was the physical path to the file *then*, but once `collectstatic` has done it's thing, everything is moved around and relative to `<project_root>/static/`.

I toyed with the idea of using symbolic links to try to match up the pre and post-`collectstatic` @import paths, but I decided that that was far too complicated and fragile in the long run.

SO... I broke down and moved all the LESS files together under `<project_root>/assets/css/`, and rationalized moving the LESS files out of the apps because since they're tied to a project-level file in order to function, they're inherently project-level themselves.

Comment: Blah! I think I'll have to do the same... My local dev compiler isn't aware of django's staticfiles.. so even if I modified my workflow to run collectstatic locally, my compiler would modify files in the /static/ dir.. A bit unfortunate. Did you end up still using staticfiles for everything but CSS?

Comment: I ended up moving my less files to `assets/less/products.less` and removed the app folder structure. One app with all of its assets feels so clean, it's too bad it's gone!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why not just configure `lessc` with a few include paths that make it so you don't have to use those relative paths? It may not be ideal or namespace-y, but neither is your solution.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sort of in the same bind and this is what I've come up with for the most recent versions of compressor and lessc to integrate with staticfiles. Hopefully this will help some other people out

As far as I can tell from experimenting, `lessc` doesn't have a notion of absolute or relative paths. Rather, it seems to maintain a search path, which includes the current directory, the containing directory of the less file, and whatever you pass to it via `--include-path`

so in my configuration for compressor I put

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/less', 'lessc --include-path=%s {infile} {outfile}' % STATIC_ROOT),
)
```

Say, after running `collectstatic` I have bootstrap living at

```
STATIC_ROOT/bootstrap/3.2.0/bootstrap.css.
```

Then from any less file, I can now write

```
@import (less, reference) "/bootstrap/3.2.0/bootstrap.css"
```

which allows me to use the bootstrap classes as less mixins in any of my less files!

Every time I update a less file, I have to run collectstatic to aggregate them in a local directory so that compressor can give `less` the right source files to work on. Otherwise, compressor handles everything smoothly. You can also use `collectstatic -l` to symlink, which means you only need to collect the files when you add a new one.

I'm considering implementing a management command to smooth out the development process that either subclasses `runserver` to call `collectstatic` each time the server is reloaded, or uses `django.utils.autoreload` directly to call `collectstatic` when things are updated.

Edit (2014/12/01): My approach as outlined above requires a local static root. I was using remote storage with offline compression in my production environment, so deployment requires a couple extra steps. In addition to calling `collectstatic` to sync the static files to the remote storage, I call `collectstatic` with different django config file that uses local storage. After I have collected the files locally, I can call 'compress', having configured it to upload the result files to remote storage, but look in local storage for source files.