# django-compressor, LESS, relative @import and relative url()

Tags: django, less, django-compressor

I'm using django-compressor + LESS.

I have a problem with relative `@import` inside .less file and relative `url(../image.png)` in included `.less` file.

I will explain. I have next folder structure:

```
common/  # Django app with some common stuff, e.g. common button styles
   static/
     common/
       less/buttons.less
       img/icon.png
blog/
  static/
    blog/
      less/blog_buttons.less
```

Inside `buttons.less` I have mixin for button:

```
.button() {
    color: white;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    background: gray url(../img/icon.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Inside `blog_buttons.less` I use this mixin:

```
@import "../../../../common/static/common/less/buttons";

.blog_button {
    .button;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

And here is the problem:

when django-compress pre-compiles my `blog_buttons.less` - button background points to `/static/blog/img/icon.png` (404 Not Found). But it should point to `/static/common/img/icon.png`

Am I doing something wrong? (I think that it should be a kind of very common situation)

Answer (score 0):

If your static paths are configured correctly, you should be able to treat both `common/static` and `blog/static` as if they were the same folder. Your import statement should rather look like this:

```
@import "../../common/less/buttons";
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer to this question is probably relevant. You may also want to add the '--relative-url' argument to lessc
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25929152/559629.